# Using Default List Forms for Edit & View

Tags: list, infopath

Is it possible to configure a SharePoint 2010 list to the default form for editing and viewing while displaying my custom InfoPath form only for new items?

Comment: +1 Thanks for drawing attention to this bug (Sharepoint Designer 2010 disrespects default manual settings without laborious tweaking them and Infopath Designer 2010 overwriting them on next  publishing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use mixed, i.e. both Infopath and default Sharepoint form templates, after creating Infopath form for and publishing to a list, you should remove association with Infopath form template and only then to choose again a specific as[x web part page...

Navigate to list > on ribbon **List** tab (under List Tools) > **Settings** > **List settings** > **Form Settings** > choose radiobutton **"Use default Sharepoint form from the server"** without checking **"Delete the Infopath form from the server"** > OK

[image: choose radiobutton "Use default Sharepoint form from the server" without checking "Delete the Infopath form from the server"]

Only then, in Sharepoint Designer 2010 **Lists and Libraries** > choose a List >  in section **Forms** choose

- newifs.aspx

and press on ribbon "**Set as default**"

[image]

Now, Infopath form web part page (linked eventually to infopath template) is used for new (aka create aka add) a list item while default sharepoint web parts (using default sharepoint lisr template) page for View and and Edit.

And you should repeat all the steps after each (quick) publish from Infopath Designer. No other choice, O am afraid...

Actually I posted in msdn forum about this user-unfriendliness:

- [How to make Infopath Designer 2010 respect the default selected types (New, Edit, Display) for list forms?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/6af397b4-466f-4619-aba1-517f6367bd2c/)

Comment: +1000 if I could...been searching for hours trying to figure out why sharepoint isn't doing what I tell it to!

Comment: This works great, except when using the Info Path form as a webpart on another page. I have a "New Account" page setup, which has an infopath webpart in it, showing the "New" view. Anyway, if i turn off using Infopath forms in List Settings -> Form Settings, then the Infopath Webpart no longer sees the list as an option having Infopath forms.  Any ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default view for a form inside SharePoint Designer. Just edit the list forms to point to the .aspx page that uses your InfoPath form, then assign it to the New Form type.

[image]

Comment: I see that but after you create a new custom Infopath form things seem not so straight forward. It seems infopath takes over after that and these setting no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

If the option "Use default Sharepoint form from the server" does not appear, you can go to Designer to modify the element. Inside it, in the forms section delete all the addresses that appear there. And so sharepoint uses the default froms again