# Sharepoint modal popup don't shown when the Infopath form are on the site

Tags: development, infopath, error, event-receivers, modal-dialog

I tried to add Infopath form on my project, but when I add the Infopath form some of the PopUp which is correlated with Infopath and shows errors od data didn't show What should I do to show A Modal Popup after used an Infopath form? Please help.

I putt this code, and nothing has shown When Infopath template is included. If it's included defoultTemplate Sharepoint all templates are shown:

```
   if (dzienStart > dzienStop)
           {
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8).TotalMilliseconds);
               properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
               properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/Add4/OutOfRange.aspx";
               properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot save this list item at this time";
               return;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot grasp what you are asking and in which context ("putts this code") but I shall try to make some comments:

- Infopath code-behind is client-side code and your code is server-side
- Published to Sharepoint Infopath form templates are available for use through IPFS - Sharepoint Server Infopath Form Service as an Infopath Web Part in ASPX Infopath Web Part pages;
- IPFS is available only on enterpse Sharepoint Server or enterprises Sharepoint online (Office 365) plans (but NOT through free Sharepoint Foundation)
- In order to use both default sharepoint form templates and Infopath from templates in dialog/popups, you should [tweak and work around a little](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43788/using-default-list-forms-for-edit-view/43816#43816)