# How Could I edit InfoPath in Visual Studio

Tags: development, infopath, event-receivers

If I add InfoPath from Infopath Designer its blocked me all the Modal Dialog fired from Event Receiver. I want to edit InfoPath form to don't block My Sharepoint Modal Dialog. Now no one dialog boxed fired from Event Receiver. If I have got a Default form without InfoPath, the dialog boxes are firing when it's caught an Error.

Here Is my code of setting Dialog Boxes in Event Receiver:

```
          if (dzienStart > dzienStop)
           {
               properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
               properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/Add4/OutOfRange.aspx";
               properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot save this list item at this time";


               return;
           }
```

Now after error raises it's clearing me Infopath form, and no dialog shown.

Comment: Why I cant stop after sending data and rises the error from Event Receiver

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered this your question in my replies to your questions:

- [InfoPath, and Calling a instation of Template InfoPath from Event Receiver](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/54911)
- [Sharepoint modal popup don't shown when the Infopath form are on the site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/54910)

In other words, if you do not want to create-maintain your own alternatives to Sharepoint and Infopath and/or to hack-override-subvert their intended usage with all consequences of development&maintenance horrors, you should first acquaint yourself with their principles and follow them instead of trying to insistingly trying to hack and subvert them.