# InfoPath, and Calling a instation of Template InfoPath from Event Receiver

Tags: development, infopath, event-receivers

I want to call a form of InfoPath from Event Receiver. How Could I set a field infopath a Values, from Event Receivers to sets a Values on infopath fields which could I Validate and show or hide a sending button of Infopath form. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can OOTB (without using 3d-party tools or hacking subverting sharepoint model and architecture) call Infopath form code.

Answering the 2nd question:

- "How Could I set a field infopath a Values"

you should acquaint yourself with Web Part connections (as published to Sharepoint Infopath form templates are available and can be use as Infopath Web Parts in ASPX Web Part pages):

- [Video: Create Web Part connections using SharePoint Designer 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-web-part-connections-using-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA102191896.aspx)
- my answer to [Webparts connection](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23088/79964.aspx#79964) question

**Update (in answer to comment):**
Let's start from the beginning, there are:

- an .XSN Infopath form template created by Infopath Designer
- which upon its publishing to Sharepoint is available as Infopath Form Web Part for using in dialogs or in Sharepoint's ASPX Web Part Pages
- Infopath .XML data forms created dynamicaly on the basis of .XSN Infopath form template
- The latter are used (opened, created, rendered, changed/modified/edited, deleted) through IPFS - Sharepoint Server's Infopath Forms Service - in browser, server side
  or by Infopath Filler on client machines

So, what do you call by "Infopath form" and in which context? which type of Infopath form, where are its template published and Infopath XML data form (or Infopath Web Part in a Web Part page?) on its basis stored?

**Update2:**
After answering, I googled on it since I started to doubt in my answer and  search results confirm what I've answered:

- [Event Handlers/Receivers and (InfoPath) Form Content Types](http://www.signaturesterling.com/blog/post/Event-HandlersReceivers-and-%28InfoPath%29-Form-Content-Types.aspx)

which is for sharepoint library.

And from your previous questions I understood that [you were dealing with sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/connecting-infopath-with-the-data-from-the-list) where, in case of Infopath form of type Sharepoint List Form the code internals are locked or depends on how you use it

Comment: But i only want to send Values from Event Receiver to the InfoPath form to see if no errors on Items Adding the button of sending data in InfoPath is shown or not.