# Disassociate InfoPath form from SP List for Edit Form Only

Tags: infopath, form

I have an InfoPath form that shows whenever I create a new item or edit a list item. Is it possible to use SharePoint's default form for Editing list items, but still keep a customized InfoPath form for New Items? I know about reverting to the SharePoint form under List Settings -> Form Settings but I only want to do that for the Edit Item Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my answer to the question:

- [Using Default List Forms for Edit & View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43816/8319)

that, as I believe, should answer your quesstion too