# Display text as Italic for Description while creating a field in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

While creating a Field in sharepoint 2010 can we make the description text as Italic ? If so can you please provide me sample. I have tried using `<i></i>` but with out no luck.

Comment: You want the field name to display in italic? InfoPath is the way to go.

Comment: No I dont want to use info path sorry i only want in Editform.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As teylnn said the above option through Designer works. But we can do through the Jquery as well by using the below . I tried like this and all my description Fields are Bold and Italic.

```
$(".ms-formtable td").css({"font-weight":"bold", "font-style":"italic"});

$(".ms-formtable td span").css({"font-style":"normal", "font-weight":"normal"});
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 1):

See this thread how you could do it for the Editform.aspx only.

[using-default-list-forms-for-edit-view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43788/using-default-list-forms-for-edit-view)

Make your change in InfoPath, deploy the forms which will create the new second forms newifs.aspx, editifs.aspx and displayifs.aspx for the list.

Open SharePoint designer, navigate to the list and right click on the original forms dispform.aspx and newitem.aspx and set them as default. Delete the Newifs.aspx and Displayifs.aspx.

Now you should have the original listforms except your custom editifs.aspx form.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to format the form's labels. If you want to do this for just one list, you can

- create a text file with the required CSS and upload it to a document library on the site
- open the list in the browser and select the Form Web Parts drop-down
- select the "Default Edit Form"
- Add a Content Editor Web Part to the form and move it to the bottom
- edit the CEWP and set its Content Link to the file you uploaded in the first step.
- make sure the CEWP chrome is set to "none" and save the form

The text file should contain the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-standardheader{
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

When you edit an existing form, the labels will be displayed in italic font. The CSS used in the screenshot also adds a yellow background to the label.

[image]

Edit: for the field description, the situation is a bit more complex. In the standard form, this text has no specific style applied that could be changed. You need to create a custom form for the list in SharePoint Designer:

- Open the list in SharePoint Designer and edit the EditForm.aspx
- find the original form's `IsVisible` attribute and set it to `false`, so the line reads `<IsVisible>false</IsVisible>`
- click below the existing form web part and on the Insert ribbon click the "Edit Item Form" and select the desired list.
- In this new form you can see all list fields, their labels and their descriptions. You can re-arrange them and manually edit the XSLT to include styles or other formatting.

Comment: I want it for Description of a field

Comment: See my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

Little improved version of accomplishing this via jquery

```
$(document).ready
(
     function ()
    {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("EditForm.aspx") > -1)
        {
          $(".ms-formbody").css({ "font-weight":"bold","font-style":"italic"});
          $(".ms-formbody span").css({"font-style":"normal","font-weight": "normal"});
        }
   }
);
```